# Load wordpress templates with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I want to load my templates with ajax, but I am having struggles (doesn't work at all), mostly with the PHP I guess. I am trying to get whatever template is the correct one using the ID to get the template slug, but doesn't seem to be working.

Here is my code so far:

```
function theme_js() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajaxstuff', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'ajaxstuff', 'ajaxify', array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
    ));

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_js' );

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_submit', 'my_ajax_submit' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_submit', 'my_ajax_submit' );

function my_ajax_submit() {

    $pageUrl = $_REQUEST['URL'];
    $postid = url_to_postid( $pageUrl );         
    $post = get_post($postid);
    $pageSlug = get_page_template_slug($postid);

    if ($post) {
    setup_postdata($post);

        get_template_part( $pageSlug );

    }

    exit();
}
```

And my JS:

```
    (function($){

   $('body').on('click', 'a', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var URL = $(this).attr('href');

        animationFunction();

        var ajaxPromise = $.ajax({
            url: ajaxify.ajaxurl,
            type: "post",
            data: {
                action: 'my_ajax_submit',
                url: URL
            },
            dataType: "html"
        });

        var animationPromise = animationFunction();
        $.when(ajaxPromise, animationPromise).done(function(data) {
            $('#page-wrap').html(data[0]);
            TweenMax.to('.page', 0.35, { alpha: 1 });
        });

    });

    function animationFunction() {

      var deferred = $.Deferred();

      TweenMax.to('.page', 0.35, { alpha: 0, onComplete: deferred.resolve  });

      return deferred.promise();

    }

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pageUrl = $_REQUEST['URL'];
```

`$_REQUEST` contains an associative array and array indexes are case sensitive, so:

```
$pageUrl = $_REQUEST['url'];
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. However the page content is still not being loaded, even if i set it to get_template_part('page'); instead of $pageSlug. You see anything else that looks wrong?

Comment: Does the console in chrome developer tools give any errors?

Comment: Nope no errors. But if I change url from url: `ajaxStuff.ajaxurl` to just `url: url` and remove the function call from data it is working, why might this be?

Comment: Well the url should be `admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )`. The Network tab and the Console inside the Chrome Developer tools should give you all the information about whether the JavaScript works or not.

Comment: Got it working. I passed the wrong function name to action *dooh*.